# Trying to Batch Process from Illustrator to PNG In Photoshop

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, export, batch-processing

I've got 5300+ files to convert.

Here's what I want to happen with Batch Processing:

1. Open an .ai file in Photoshop and have the width and height in pixels be auto entered [Problem is that the open action records the file as well as the name of the file. If I try to check show dialog I have to manually choose the next file in line and manually enter the dimensions I need]
2. Export as a .png file [Problem is the Export as PNG can't be recorded as part of an action. I tried Insert Menu Item, but get "Select unknown menu item" in the action]

I just don't know what to do.

I'm in Mojave on a very old Mac running PS 22.5.1 and AI 25.4.1 (both barely), the newest versions I can run.

Please, no comments like "By a New Mac (or PC)" or "You're asking too much". I can't afford a new machine and these kind of comments don't help.

If you have a script that runs in Terminal, I'll need step-by-step hand-holding and will have a lot of questions.

FYI, I'm ex-Apple. Started on a Mac June '84 when I was 21. Was QA for HyperCard 2.0 and the Mac IILC. Been tech support for Apple and Symantec. Started with Illustrator '88 and PhotoShop a few years later.

Thanks in advance,

Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little hard to answer, and I am not 100% sure this will work for your particular use case.

Anyway, here are the steps.

1. Before you begin make sure all your AI files are in one folder (the source folder), and create another folder for the PNG files (the destination folder)
2. Open a new blank file in Photoshop, and **begin recording** an action.
3. Open one of the AI files.
4. In the dialog that pops up, do not change the size dimensions, instead change the resolution. This will automatically import the images with larger image dimentions.
5. Do File > Export > Save for Web (Legacy). Choose PNG 24 as the file type
6. Hit Save, and save this to the same folder
7. Close the open document, and when prompted, **do not** save it.
8. **Stop the recording**
9. Go into the folder where you saved the PNG and just delete it.

To run the Action on a batch

1. Do *File > Automate > Batch*.
2. Choose the settings shown in the dialog below. Specifically: *Override Action "Open" Commands* and *Suppress File Open Options Dialogs*.
3. Make sure to select the source and destination folders.
4. Hit OK to run it

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked!